# Check a String and output false if it doesn't contain the desired element from a List

Tags: python, list, replace, count

Could someone help me why does this code turns TRUE while I want it to turn False, because i want the output like: 
 Yes the string does contain x but contains Y too let's say x is asd and Y is asd 2 (with space) There is my code :

```
text = "asd 1"
Should_contain = ["asd 1"]
Shouldnt_contain = ["asd", "asdd"]
contains_desired_string = any(x in text for x in Should_contain)
contains_bad_string = any(x in text for x in Shouldnt_contain)
print(contains_desired_string, contains_bad_string)
```

(If any of the not wanted elements are in the List, it should print False).
SO it should print True False  INSTEAD of True True 
I think that there might be the problem because of the space.
For example if that's a webscraper that scrapes iphone listings let's say there is an iphone 6 and a iphone 6s,bot contains iphone 6 but the two listings are whole differents ones, therefore it makes sense to filter them like ,yes it contains iphone 6 but it contains iphone 6s too,therefore the program will let you know if that's an iphone 6 or iphone 6s listing,  I hope that's a clear anwser for the next questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
counter = 0
    if "asd" in text:
        counter = -1
    counter_haha = 0

    for x in Should_contain:
        counter +=text.count(x)

    for x in Shouldnt_contain:
        counter_haha += text.count(x)

    if (counter > 1 and counter_haha > 0) or counter == 0:
        print(text+"That means Yes it contains X and contains Y too")
    elif counter == 1 and counter_haha == 1:
        print(text+"That means Yes it contains X but it does not contain Y")
```

(X=asd 1 Y=asd or asdd)
For example if that's a webscraper that scrapes iphone listings let's say there is an iphone 6 and a iphone 6s,bot contains iphone 6 but the two listings are whole differents ones, therefore it makes sense to filter them like ,yes it contains iphone 6 but it contains iphone 6s too,therefore the program will let you know if that's an iphone 6 or iphone 6s listing,  I hope that's a clear anwser for the next questions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community It anwsers my question, just nobody understands it ofr some reason, for example if that's a webscraper that scrapes iphone listings let's say there is an iphone 6 and a iphone 6s,bot contains iphone 6 but the two listings are whole differents ones, therefore it makes sense to filter them like ,yes it contains iphone 6 but it contains iphone 6s too,therefore the program will let you know if that's an iphone 6 or iphone 6 s listing,  I hope that's a clear anwser for the next questions

Answer (score 0):

[Any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) functions returns True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable. In your case `contains_bad_string` is true because the input string `text` contains `'asd'` which is an element in `Shouldnt_contain` list.

As per your comment `If any of the not wanted elements are in the List, it should print False` , you can change `contains_bad_string` in this way

```
contains_bad_string =  not any(x in text for x in Shouldnt_contain)
```

Comment: Not that was the problem,I understand that a string can contain other strings,and I have already posted the solution<br> ```counter = 0
    if "asd" in text:
        counter = -1
    counter_haha = 0

    for x in Should_contain:
        counter +=text.count(x)

    for x in Shouldnt_contain:
        counter_haha += text.count(x)

    if (counter > 1 and counter_haha > 0) or counter == 0:
        print(text+"That means Yes it contains X and contains Y too")
    elif counter == 1 and counter_haha == 1:
        print(text+"That means Yes it contains X but it does not contain Y")```